# How to backup maas database

Tags: backup, maas, restore

Is there any recommended way to backup/restore maasdb ? I tried simple dump, then reinstall and restore but i ended up with 2 clusters, one which was disconnected with nodes and one connected but with 0 nodes. The idea behind this is to be able to migrate maas to different server or perform restore in case of hw failure.